# Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined, from React.Component static funtion

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a React.Component and i want to call this static function from the many different React.Component.

```
class Categories extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getCheckedCategories = this.getCheckedCategories.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      checked: [],
      unchecked: []
    };
  }

  static getCheckedCategories() {
    return this.state.checked;
  }
}
```

So I tried to connect the function.

```
import Categories from './product/checkboxes';

class FullWidthGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const checkedCategories = Categories.getCheckedCategories();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static` functions can't access `this`, i.e. static method calls are made directly on the class and are not callable on instances of the class. You can read more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).

So in your case you could do:

```
class Categories extends Component {
  state = {
    checked: [],
    unchecked: []
  };

  static getCheckedCategories = (klass) => {
    return klass.state.checked
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>{Categories.getCheckedCategories(this)}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pnevvf?file=index.js).

Comment: Same question, Then how can I do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

That's the purpose of static function. It cannot access the instance (`this`).
You can have multiple instances of class but only one static function/property.

As a workaround (depend on what you want to do), you can use static property to store your state:

```
class Categories extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Categories.state = {
      checked: [],
      unchecked: []
    };
  }

  static getCheckedCategories() {
    return Categories.state.checked;
  }
}
```

However it won't work with `setState` since it is an instance method.

Imagine situation when you have muptiple `Categories` components and each one has different checked/unchecked categories. What would then `Categories.getCheckedCategories()` function returns?

If you want to have shared state (checked categories), I would recommend you to pull out the state out of the component. For example store it in parent component and pass it as props to child components. Or use state library like redux. You could also use react's context to manage shared state.

Comment: Then how can I do what I want?

Comment: Okay, can i setState Categories? Something like Categories.setState {}

Comment: @iLoveTatiaGaruchava that's not a good idea. since you can have multiple components but only one static function